# ROI analysis of a Z-Score map

Tags: neuroimaging

I have a brain z-score image wich is the result of some test. The image is in the SPM space.

How can I perfrom a ROI analisis of different zones? And obtain some statistics for each place.

Comment: This question is far, far too broad.